# Opening modal in list in Scala HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, scala, bootstrap-4

I am trying to open a modal window in a list of items (attachments more specifically) and I cant seem to get the record ID from the list. I open the new modal window with Scala, and I always get error because value record is invalid.

```
@(recordList: List[assets.Attachment])

@if(recordList == null || recordList.isEmpty()) {
} else {
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="attachment-player-datatable" class="table table-striped 
            table-bordered table-vcenter">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><small>Naziv</small></th>
                <th><small>Datum</small></th>
                <th class="text-center"><small><i class="fa fa-flash"></i></small></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @for(record <- recordList) {
                <tr id="attachment-@record.getId()">
                    <td><strong><a href="@record.getUrl()">@record.getTitle()</a></strong></td>
                    <td>@record.getFormattedOnlyDate()</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a id="delete-attachment-action" href="#modal-new-player-attachment" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@record.getId()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                        </a>
                        <i id="delete-attachment-loader" class="fa fa-spinner 
                       fa-2x fa-spin text-primary" style="display:none;"></i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
@playerFolder.attachmentRemoveModal(record.getId())
```

Comment: How is this related to `java`? Java and javascript are 2 absolut different languages

Comment: @B001ᛦ this question isn't about Javascript. It looks to me to be a Twirl template for [Playframework](https://www.playframework.com/), which can be used with both Scala and Java. If OP is using Java for the rest of their app, it's a perfectly reasonable tag (though I would argue [tag:playframework] would be more appropriate).

Comment: I am sorry, I meant PlayFramework but immediately associated Java into it. I am very sorry for misleading info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error is being caused by this line:

```
@playerFolder.attachmentRemoveModal(record.getId())
```

This reference to `record` is outside the `for` loop it is defined in (`@for(record <- recordList) {...}`). You can't reference variables outside where they are defined (without importing or doing something similar... not applicable here). For example:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> for (elem <- list) {
     |   println(elem)
     | }
1
2
3

scala> elem
<console>:12: error: not found: value elem
       elem
       ^
```

In this scenario, `elem` is only available inside the for loop. If you try to reference it outside the loop, the compiler doesn't know what you're trying to reference and complains.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see now why this isn't possible. I will need to find a workaround somehow.

Comment: I solved it later with using data-id and passing in the record.getId(), then I retrieved it in JS and it works now.